# Best way to define relationships in an object model?

Tags: c#, database, database-design, object-model

When building an `object model` that map a `classes` to database tables, how do you specify the relationship to other entities ?

Example :

```
Category
----------------------
CategoryId  INT     PK
Name        VARCHAR
Description VARCHAR

Product
----------------------
ProductId   INT     PK
CategoryId  INT     FK
Name        VARCHAR
UnitPrice   DECIMAL
UnitInStock INT


class Category 
{
     public int CategoryId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public List<Product> Products { get; set; } //for navigation only
}

class Product
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
     public int UnitInStock { get; set; }
}
```

What is the best way to define a relationship to the other entity ?

```
class Product
{
     //...
     public Category Category;
}
```

or

```
class Product
{
     //...
     public int CategoryId;
}
```

or both ? (one for database binding (`int CategoryId`) one for navigation (`Category 
Category`)

```
class Product
{
     //...
     public int CategoryId;
     public Category Category;
}
```

Comment: Are you using some ORM like entity framework? If not I suggest you do so.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you need from your model in terms of relationship. By putting any sort of reference to `Category` into your `Product` you are creating a bi-directional relationship at model level. This may be necessary at DB level from a data integrity point of view but it doesn't mean your model has to follow suit, it doesn't always make sense to do that.

In my opinion, `Product` shouldn't know anything about `Category` because it has no need to. A `Product` can exist on it's own without being associated with a `Category`. However, if you feel a `Product` *should* know about it's `Category` then by all means add the property in.

> Id property vs Navigation property

This, again, depends on what your requirements are. Usually it's more future proof to use the navigation property as the `ID` property would come down as part of that anyway. However, you may be adding extra overhead pulling down the full object when really all you need is the `ID`.

Comment: "In my opinion, Product shouldn't know anything about Category because it has no need to". If you are using repositories, when adding a new product to Product repository, how do you specify to which Category it belongs to ?

Comment: @tigrou that's an implementation detail which you would have to work out. However, generally you would add the product to that particular category - you wouldn't add a product *with* a category. With your current setup, you need to have a category before you can add a product which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you need backnavigation, add the main class itself as a variable; but if you do not need (or if you do not expect to need) you can just add the identifier.

But, I think you should just select one of the ways and implement it. If you try to use both methods, it may lead to problems. For example, assume that in some classes you have added the main class as a backnavigation property; then what if you do not need in some situations; you will make some unnecessary db queries or you will have nulls in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you folowing code. I use it to keep relations between entities (object represtentation of data instance from database ie. Consumer, Book). It allows to read content at first reference to related object.

```
public class EntityHandler<T, V>
        where T : Entity<V>, new()
        where V : DataObject
    {
        private long myDataObjectID;
        private T myEntityObject;
        public delegate Entity<V> GetEntityObject(long oid);

        private GetEntityObject GetEntityObjectFunction;

        private Entity<V> HandledEntity
        {
            set
            {
                if (myEntityObject == null)
                {
                    myEntityObject = (T)value;
                }
            }
            get { return myEntityObject; }
        }

        public EntityHandler(GetEntityObject extCntrGetBO, long oid)
        {
            myDataObjectID = oid;
            GetEntityObjectFunction = extCntrGetBO;
        }

        public T o
        {
            get
            {
                if (myEntityObject == null)
                {
                    myEntityObject = (T)GetEntityObjectFunction(myDataObjectID);
                }
                return myEntityObject;
            }
        }

        public long ID
        {
            get { return myDataObjectID; }
            set
            {
                myDataObjectID = value;
                myEntityObject = null;
            }
        }
    }
```